# diff line-format: Show delete, new, and changed lines?

Tags: linux, shell

backup.txt

```
user1:password:17002:0:99:7:::
user2:password:17003:0:99:7:::
user3:password:17004:0:99:7:::
```

"main.txt" is same with "backup.txt". If I rename "user1", add a new user, and remove "user2" in "main.txt". "main.txt" seems like:

```
username1:password:17002:0:99:7:::
user3:password:17004:0:99:7:::
newUser:password:17005:0:99:7:::
```

after that I use following command for compare two files:

```
diff --unchanged-line-format="" --old-line-format=":%dn: %L" --new-line-format=":%dn: %L" backup.txt main.txt
```

...with the actual output:

```
:1: user1:password:17002:0:99:7:::
:2: user2:password:17003:0:99:7:::
:1: username1:password:17002:0:99:7:::
:3: newUser:password:17005:0:99:7:::
```

However, my intended output was:

```
:1c: user1:password:17002:0:99:7:::
:2d: user2:password:17003:0:99:7:::
:1c: username1:password:17002:0:99:7:::
:3a: newUser:password:17005:0:99:7:::
```

like this. These characters are enable for default "diff" command using. How can I enable these characters for line formatting. Is it possible?

Comment: you mean you want diff to use those characters to show lines that are deleted, changed, or added? Please spell this out, rather than leaving it for the reader to assume your intent from context.

Comment: (Also, `diff` isn't actually part of the shell, making this more a question about your operating system's tools than a shell question as such).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LTYPE`s offered by both BSD and GNU diff are "old", "new", and "unchanged". You thus can't distinguish between "new" and "changed".

That said, to get *some* distinctions in your format strings, you need to fill them out correctly. In `%dn`, both the `d` and the `n` are consumed (the former specifying a decimal value, the `n` specifying that it refer to the line number, or the number of lines modified, depending on context). Thus, if you want any extra characters (such as a `c`, `d` or `a`), you need to add those characters after that substitution has complete.

```
# declaring functions to allow testing without creating files on-disk
backup () { printf '%s\n' user1:password:17002:0:99:7::: user2:password:17002:0:99:7::: user3:password:17002:0:99:7:::; }
main () { printf '%s\n' username1:password:17002:0:99:7::: user3:password:17004:0:99:7::: newUser:password:17005:0:99:7:::; }

diff \
  --unchanged-line-format=":%dnu: %L" \
  --old-line-format=":%dnd: %L" \
  --new-line-format=":%dnn: %L" \
  <(backup) <(main)
```

Comment: How do I add color to it?

Comment: For GNU diff, it's the same here as in any other context: `--color=always` to force it, or `--color=auto` to turn colorization on only when output is going directly to a tty; in either case `TERM` needs to be set so diff knows which kind of color codes to use. Adding color codes makes the content no longer a valid diff, so if you want to be able to apply the results with the `patch` tool, using `always` is probably undesirable.